# How to write a script to kill & clean the resources of executing process?

Tags: shell, scripting, c, c++

I have an application running in c language (my_process.c) and a script (stop_process.sh) to stop the application and clean up all resources held by the process.

In the application code, let's say I want call stop_process script for some reason, it looks like stop_process is getting killed after the line (`kill -9 my_process`) and is not executing the rest of the script. I think it is getting killed because the script is sending SIGKILL to parent process.

my_process.c

```
function1() {
    system(nohup /home/admin/stop_process.sh < /dev/null &);
}

int main() {
    .....
    ......
    function1();
    .....
    .....
}
```

stop_process.sh

```
cleanup 
.......
.......
kill -9 my_process
kill -9 xxx
kill -9 yyy
......
.......
cleanup
```

After the "kill -9 my_process" line, I see this message:

```
Jan 17 21:28:22 Signal 15 (TERM) caught by ps (procps-ng version 3.3.10).
Jan 17 21:28:22 ps:display.c:66: please report this bug
```

How can I write a script that can be called from c to kill C process and restart the process at the end of cleanup?

Comment: Why not the C program managing everything and not calling bash?

Answer (score 0):

Your stop_process script appears to be successfully killing your `my_process`; the trouble, as you saw, is that `my_process` then dies and cannot execute any more code. To restart `my_process`, I'd suggest a differently-named script that kills and restarts `my_process`, versus just stopping it:

## /home/admin/restart_process.sh

```
# ...
kill -9 my_process
kill -9 xxx
kill -9 yyy
# ...
my_process
```

## my_process.c

```
function1() {
    system(nohup /home/admin/restart_process.sh < /dev/null);
}
```

Note that there's no point to calling the shell script in the background.